# Android Marquee Text In Listview with Multiple Item

Tags: android, listview, text, marquee

Could anyone help me how to scroll textview horizontally in list view using marquee text. I am using marquee text in simple textview its working fine when same concept I use in listview textview its not working/scrolling please help me.! Thanks
**Here is my xml single list item file**

```
<br><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list_text"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#cc0000"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my Java file**

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);<br>
            TextView text=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.list_text);<br>
            text.setSelected(true);<br>
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item,R.id.list_text, s);<br>
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Can we see your code? Whatever you did.And did you make a custom layout for listview item?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a minimal code example of your problem.

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: <TextView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/list_text"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#cc0000"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    this is my single list item textview in layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are inflated a view that is same type of the item view but that is not the item view. To modify the item view, you need to override the getView() method of the adapter. Try the code below:

```
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.list_text, s){
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_text);
                tv.setSelected(true);
                return convertView;
            }
        };
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```